# How to fill a textfield and pressing a button multiple times in order in Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, automated-tests

I want to automatically fill out a form and then click the **Subscribe** button multiple times on this certain website. But somehow the behaviors are inconsistent and the actions aren't performed in a correct order.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

browser = webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver.exe")
browser.get("https://www.facen.co/")

emails = ["mikhail67@gmail.com", "konovalov878@gmail.com", "miruki451@gmail.com"]

# send a list of random emails
for email in emails:
    sub_textfield = browser.find_element_by_id("comp-ka58ijvyinput")
    sub_button = browser.find_element_by_id("comp-ka58ijw9link")

    ActionChains(browser).move_to_element(sub_textfield).send_keys(email).move_to_element(sub_button).click().perform()
```

I tried to keep order of executions using `ActionChains`, but it doesn't seem to be working. What could be the problem?

Comment: Why are you using `ActionChains` at all? It doesn't look like it's necessary here.

Comment: @JeffC When I try to fill out the form and then click the Subscribe button, it just fills the form constantly and presses the button without any order at all. I thought using `ActionChains` would keep the order of executions. How should I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding some delays using the time module

and also DO NOT execute the last line as a whole thing in a single line
use name spacing and put them in different lines and add some delays so this will give the computer some time to know whats happening and let the thing load

That could be the problem sometimes that the code has run faster than the page has loaded

Comment: But using any kind of `wait` in Selenium is bad practice.

Comment: @HuyTran Using waits in Selenium is definitely not a bad practice. It's necessary many times. The bad practices come in with the type of wait that you use. Sleeps and using implicit waits are bad practices but WebDriverWait is a best practice.

Answer (score 0):

Typically something like this would not need to use `ActionChains`. It doesn't sound like you have a timing issue but I would add a wait to the first line in your loop just to be safe.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

browser = webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver.exe")
browser.get("https://www.facen.co/")

emails = ["mikhail67@gmail.com", "konovalov878@gmail.com", "miruki451@gmail.com"]

# send a list of random emails
for email in emails:
    WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "comp-ka58ijvyinput")).send_keys(email)
    browser.find_element_by_id("comp-ka58ijw9link").click()
```

Comment: I tried to run this and it didn't even start to scroll down and find the input field. After showing the input field explicitly, the order of executions is again messed up. You can try to run it on the site that I provided.